# "Vieta's-formulas" on matrices

Tags: matrices

Let matrices $X $ and $ Y$  satisfy the equality $Z^2+AZ+B=0$
where $A , B$ are real matrices and $\det(X - Y)\ne 0$   Prove

1. $ \operatorname{tr} X + \operatorname{tr} Y  = - \operatorname{tr} A$
2. $\det X \det Y = \det B $

Proof 1) $(X+Y)(X-Y)+XY-YX+A(X-Y)=0\Rightarrow X+Y+(XY-YX)(X-Y)^{-1}+A=0$

As $ \operatorname{tr} PQ= \operatorname{tr} QP$ we have $\operatorname{tr} (XY-YX)(X-Y)^{-1}=0$ entailing the result.

2. We have $(X+A)X=-B$ and $(Y+A)Y=-B$. The result follows if $\det XY=0.$

If $\det X\ne 0$ and $\det Y\ne0$ then $X-Y=B(Y^{-1}-X^{-1})$
Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are permutable, we can easily obtain the result.

Is it possible to achieve this result without such an assumption, or is it necessary to look for a counterexample?

Comment: You missed an "$=0$" in the first implication.

Comment: 1) $tr (XYZ)=tr (YXZ)$, where $Z=(X-Y)^{-1}$

Comment: 2)  if $XY=YX$ multiply the equation $X-Y=B(Y^{-1}-X^{-1})$ by $XY$ and cut down $X-Y$.

Comment: (1) The equality $\operatorname{tr}(XYZ)=\operatorname{tr}(YXZ)$ does not hold in general. Consider e.g. $X=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0},\,Y=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}$ and $Z=\pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&1}$. The trace equality does hold when $Z=(X-Y)^{-1}$, but you have yet to justify that. (2) OK, thanks. I haven’t never seen such usage of word. In linear algebra, we say that $X$ and $Y$ “commute”.

Comment: Also, you don‘t actually need $X$ and $Y$ to commute. Since $X-Y=B(Y^{-1}-X^{-1})=BX^{-1}(X-Y)Y^{-1}$, the result follows if you take determinants on both sides.

Answer (score 2):

The two equalities do not necessarily hold when $X-Y$ is singular. Here is a random example:
$$
X=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 1&1},
\ Y=\pmatrix{2&0\\ 1&1},
\ A=\pmatrix{-3&1\\ -1&1},
\ B=\pmatrix{1&-1\\ -2&-2}.
$$
One can easily verify that
$$
\begin{aligned}
(X+A)X&=\pmatrix{-2&1\\ 0&2}\pmatrix{1&0\\ 1&1}=-B,\\
(Y+A)Y&=\pmatrix{-1&1\\ 0&2}\pmatrix{2&0\\ 1&1}=-B.\\
\end{aligned}
$$
However, $\operatorname{tr}(X)+\operatorname{tr}(Y)=5\ne2=-\operatorname{tr}(A)$ and $\det(X)\det(Y)=2\ne-4=\det(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot! How did I not realize straightaway?
How to fix the first statement

Let $X=P+Q, Y=P-Q\Leftrightarrow X+Y=2P, X-Y=2Q $.

Now $$X^2-Y^2+A(X-Y)=0\Leftrightarrow $P+QPQ^{-1}+A=0\Rightarrow   \operatorname{tr} X + \operatorname{tr} Y  = - \operatorname{tr} A$$

Proof of the second was completed by user 1551 in comment.